# Writing my jQuery more efficently

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two similar functions performing a responsive menu toggle via a handle on the page, see the code:

```
//responsive main navigation
    $(function() {
        var pull        = $('#pull');
            menu        = $('.main-nav ul');
            menuHeight  = menu.height();

        $(pull).on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            menu.slideToggle('fast');
        });
    });

    //responsive blog navigation
    $(function() {
        var toggle        = $('#toggle-handle');
            sidebar        = $('.blog-sidebar-wrap');
            sidebarHeight  = sidebar.height();

        $(toggle).on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            sidebar.slideToggle('fast');
        });
    });
```

My question is how can I write this so that I'm not repeating the same kind of procedure (function). Do i set up a single function and pass in the parameters? Help mostly appreciated, jQuery/Javascript beginner here!

Comment: only *"mostly"* appreciated? hah.

Comment: Can you also post your HTML structure.

Comment: Why don't your other variable declarations use `var`, just the first?

Comment: I think Arun has nailed it below, that is exactly what I was after.

Comment: @RobMorris it could be made much simpler, but I need to see your HTML to do it.

Comment: FYI, you're declaring a lot of global variables due to using `;` rather than `,` in your variable declarations.

Comment: Better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ IMO.

Comment: You want efficiency, yet you use JQuery (and I bet you are not using 10% of its functionnalities)...

Comment: @kevinB - yes just noticed that, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
//a function that creates a slide based menu
function slideMenu(ctrl, target){
    ctrl.on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        target.slideToggle('fast');
    });
}

//responsive main navigation
$(function() {
    var pull        = $('#pull');
    menu        = $('.main-nav ul');
    menuHeight  = menu.height();

    slideMenu(pull, menu)
});

//responsive blog navigation
$(function() {
    var toggle        = $('#toggle-handle');
    sidebar        = $('.blog-sidebar-wrap');
    sidebarHeight  = sidebar.height();

    slideMenu(toggle, sidebar)
});
```

Comment: Thanks, just the ticket

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(function() {

effectdemo("#pull",'.main-nav ul');
effectdemo('#toggle-handle','.blog-sidebar-wrap');

    });

function effectdemo(starter,sliderconatiner)
{
         var toggle        = $(starter);
            sidebar        = $(sliderconatiner);
            sidebarHeight  = sidebar.height();

        $(toggle).on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            sidebar.slideToggle('fast');
        });

}
```